# Can socketstream act on ss.event.on in server

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, publish-subscribe, socketstream

I am publishing messages to a Redis server with the Pub/Sub system. I am using Socketstream 0.3 with node.js to listen to and process these messages. In client code (app.js) I can act on these messages just fine using ss.event.on:

```
ss.event.on "portux", (object) ->
  # Handle messages of the type Switch 3 true (to switch 3 on) or Switch 2 false
  if object.type is "Switch" 
  sw = object.location
  # the cmd is now in the quantity field
  cmd = object.quantity
  if object.value then cmd += 'On;' else cmd += 'Off;'
  send cmd
```

However, on some of these messages I also want the system to act even if no browser is accessing the website. In other words, I'd like it to be in either app.js (or app.coffee) in root, or in server/rpc, so that it gets executed whenever the message arrives, regardless of  a browser having opened the website.

When I try to do that, I get an error message on ss.event.on (no object defined). I've also tried using ss.api.event.on but it just looks like messages can only be received in the client code. Is this true? Is there another way I can achieve what I want?

Peter

Comment: Surely you can call the code you want to execute directly if it's on the server? Why do you want to make it use socketstream pub/sub? Socketstream messages start on the server, so if you want the server to do something else then call the function. Socketstream just makes it easy to send messages from the server to every client but you don't need to use it for *everything*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the server you can just call the function directly from the same place the event is triggered.

If you're committed to the semantic paradigm of events you can theme your naming (of functions etc) in an event style.
You could also dig into Node's event-emmiter library and customise something that way.

This is all just if you want to waste your time in this way adhering to a strictly event-oriented paradigm for program organisation.

The simplest thing is as commenter Deif mentioned, just call the function directly.  From the same place you (would) trigger the event.